# how to restore ubuntu 12.04 or reinstall accidentally removed packages?

Tags: 12.04, apt

I just accidentally removed libnl-3-200, and all the relative packages have been removed, now there is now internet in my ubuntu laptop.

Is there anyway to reinstall it and all the relevant packages ?

Do I need to download each package on another machine, and copy to ubuntu or there is any single package consists all these packages ?

Please help..

Comment: look /var/cache/apt/archives/  for packages here apt-get  cache (downloades) all packages before installing.

Comment: does it do same, while uninstalling any package ?

Comment: after uninstalling also packages will be available in cache location

Comment: @PKumar .deb will be avialable if and only if you had install it before or update and not by default so mostly the OP will not find all of removed packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say you that there is no simple solution for this.

There is no magic solution to say repair what I've done. But there is still some things to do.

- Open your Ubuntu Software Center
- Under the History tab
- Go to the Removals tab

There you can find all packages that were removed accidentally (notice the date) so now as you know the missing you have to install one by one.